# Get order_id where order_id has two time x value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using Oscommeerce with old MySql version and with php version 4 on my website.

My table structure :

```
| orders_status_history_id |  orders_id |  orders_status_id |
|            1             |      22    |         3         |
|            2             |      23    |         2         |
|            3             |      24    |         5         |
|            4             |      75    |         5         |
|            5             |      25    |         5         |
|            6             |      30    |         1         |
|            7             |      26    |         2         |
|            8             |      75    |         54        |
|            10            |      22    |         5         |
|            15            |      48    |         6         |
|            16            |      52    |         8         |
|            17            |      32    |         9         |
|            18            |      75    |         54        |
|            19            |      24    |         5         |
|            22            |      20    |         8         |
|            23            |      75    |         54        |
|            ..            |      ..    |         ..        |
|            ..            |      ..    |         ..        |
```

My table has overall more than 2000000 rows.

`orders_status_history_id` column is `auto increment`.

So my question is:

How do i get `orders_id` where `orders_status_id` has two time 54 `id` ?

For examaple: 
If `orders_id` 75  has `orders_status_id`=54 then it should show me its `orders_id` 75 and if not then skip it.

So I expect output like so:

```
|     orders_status_id     |  orders_id | 
|            54            |      75    |
```

I tired following ways :

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            orders_status_history_id, orders_id, orders_status_id 
        FROM 
            orders_status_history 
        Where 
            (orders_status_history_id > ".$dal." AND orders_status_history_id < ".$al.") 
        AND 
            orders_id IN(
                    Select Distinct
                        orders_id
                    From 
                        orders_status_history 
                    Where  
                        (orders_status_history_id > ".$dal." AND orders_status_history_id < ".$al.")
                    HAVING
                        count(orders_status_id=54)>2
                )";
```

Did not work

```
SELECT 
    orders_status_history_id, orders_id, orders_status_id 
    FROM 
        orders_status_history 
    WHERE 
        (orders_status_history_id > 0 AND orders_status_history_id < 500)
    AND
        orders_id IN (
            Select 
                orders_id 
            FROM 
                orders_status_history 
            WHERE
                (orders_status_history_id > 0 AND orders_status_history_id < 1000)
            AND  
                count(orders_status_id=54) >2
        )
```

I can't find the query to fetch desired result.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select orders_id
from orders_status_history
where orders_status_id = 54
group by orders_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

If you actually want the full details, then use `join` or `in`:

```
select osh.*
from orders_status_history osh join
     (select orders_id
      from orders_status_history
      where orders_status_id = 54
      group by orders_id
      having count(*) >= 2
     ) o
     on osh.orders_id = o.orders_id;
```

Comment: Where's the group by?

Comment: @gordonLinoff It gives my this error : `Query execution was interrupted` I have 1900000+ rows ion my table

Comment: @jarlh . . . It is in there now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT orders_status_history_id, orders_id, orders_status_id
FROM orders_status_history
WHERE (orders_status_history_id > 0 AND orders_status_history_id < 500) and orders_id IN (
    SELECT orders_id
    FROM orders_status_history
    GROUP BY orders_id
    HAVING COUNT(orders_status_history_id) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
SELECT orders_id, orders_status_id
FROM test
AS r
WHERE (
    SELECT count(*) FROM test
    WHERE orders_id=r.orders_id AND orders_status_id=r.orders_status_id
)>=2
GROUP BY orders_status_id
```

Hope that works.